# When is the derivative of an ODE solution wrt the initial condition a simple exponential?

Tags: ca.classical-analysis-and-odes

Suppose we are given an autonomous ODE $y' = f(y)$ such that $y$ is smooth with respect to the initial condition.

We then have
$$(\nabla y)' = \nabla f(y) \nabla y.$$
If $\nabla f(y(t)) $ commutes with $\int_0^t f(y(s))ds$ at any time $t$, then the latter ODE has a simple solution as an exponential.

Are there general conditions when this is indeed the case? We may assume $f$ to be conservative if it helps.